The usage of 'the better to' in this sentence: is it grammatically correct?

Presupposing that an exclusion in geography requires an exclusion in
thought, the paper also considers both the moral, epistemological and
ontological dimensions of the utopia of exclusion, the better to
understand its geographical manifestations.

(source)
Is this a correct usage of 'the better'? I am familiar with 'the [comparative form]... the [comparative form]' structure, but this one seems odd to me, especially because it is followed by 'to'. Any explanations?

From "Little Red Riding Hood": Red: "Grandma, what big teeth you have!" Wolf: "The better to eat you with, my dear"

@Barmar haha, thanks, it's funny I'm reading these sophisticated scholarly publications, while a children's story is enough to learn this grammar!

to understand better is better, unless you want to sound childish.

But it's not a correct use of "both".

From Collins Dictionary:

If you do something the better to do something else, you do the first thing in order to be able to do the second thing more effectively.

"better" is used to express a comparison between doing the second thing with or without the assistance of the first thing. So in your example, considering "the moral, epistemological and ontological dimensions" makes it easier to understand the geographical manifestations.
Similarly, when the Wolf (disguised as Grandma) in "Little Red Riding Hood" says

The better to eat you with.

he's saying that having big teeth makes it easier to eat Red.

As far as an explanation: "the" in "the better" is a fossilized form of the instrumental case.  One could paraphrase that construction as "thereby better to understand..."
